# Error when implements Devise::SessionsController in request variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I followed [this guide](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/dual-authentication-using-devise-and-jwt?status=in-review) to implement Dual authentication using Devise and JWT, and when I try to login into my application, I received this error:

undefined local variable or method `request' for SessionsController:Class Did you mean? require

Code of sessions_controller.rb:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :html, :json
  clear_respond_to if request.format == 'json'
end
```

Could someone help me with this error? Thanks.

Comment: With respect, the sample in the guide is nonsense.  `clear_respond_to` is a class method that is executed when the `SessionsController` is initialised (i.e. application startup). At that point (application startup) there isn't a request yet so the line as provided makes no sense.  apneadiving has given you a good answer but keep in mind that whoever wrote the guide didn't actually ever run that code.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn, thanks for the explanation. I searched a few posts about authentication using Devise and JWT and found a few posts, just following this which seemed the more explanatory, but unfortunately ended up not working out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
before_action :trigger_clear_respond_to, if: -> { request.format == 'json' }

def trigger_clear_respond_to
  clear_respond_to
end
```